# How to refactor a piece of code not to use an async fucntion

Tags: javascript, validation, asynchronous

I am doing a code with node follow along, but at the same time I am also writing my own app based on what I learnt in my previous course and also the code along one. 
In the code along one, we have a piece of middleware that checks to make sure the user that is the logged in, is the user that owns the profile and then allows them to amend it. This has been written using an async function and it works just as it should do, but I want to write is as a non async function, but I dont get the same end result, can anyone help me in re-writing this function to a non async function?

```js
//Function to see if the current password is valid
middlewareObj.isValid = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { user } = await User.authenticate()(req.user.username, req.body.currentPassword);
  if(user) {
    //Add user to res.locals
    res.locals.user = user;
    next();
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "The password you entered does not match the current password stored in the database, please try again");
    res.redirect("back");
  }
}
```

I have tried this but it always gives truthy no matter what you enter in the currentPassword field in the form

```
//Function to see if the current email is valid
middlewareObj.isValid = (req, res, next) => {
  const user = User.authenticate()(req.user.username,
    req.body.currentPassword);
  if (user) {
    res.locals.user = user;
    next();
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "The password you entered does not match the current 
    password stored in the database, please try again");
    res.redirect("back");
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `User.authenticate()` function returns ?

Comment: Going by the tutorial, the User.authenticate returns another function with the parameters  req.user.username, req.body.currentPassword, so if the function returns true, then it runs the user if statement, if the function returns false it runs the else statement. The res.locals.user = user; can be ignored as it is to do with another middleware in the chain of events.

Comment: Is the `User.authenticate()` function async or does it return an async function ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think it is a async function and it if it returns true it validates the users input in the currentPassword field in the form by checking the user.username and the currentPassword input

Comment: The user is going to be destructed but is waiting for the higher order User.authenticate function to return a value, the authenticate function has another function inside of User.authenticate which takes 2 arguments, the req.user,username and req,body.currentPassword

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: This is to do with promises, as it has been written as an async function, so I can either use async/await, or short circuit the promise using .then(), just working on some code to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a `Promise` object (so it is truthy). If you don't use `async/await`, you can use `then` function to complete the promise and put the rest of you code in the callback:

```
//Function to see if the current password is valid
middlewareObj.isValid = function (req, res, next) => {
  (User.authenticate()(req.user.username, req.body.currentPassword)).then(({ user }) => {
    if (user) {
      //Add user to res.locals
      res.locals.user = user;
      next();
    } else {
      req.flash("error", "The password you entered does not match the current password stored in the database, please try again");
      res.redirect("back");
    }
  });
}
```

See the documentation of [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer that worked in the end,

```
//Function to see if the current password is valid
middlewareObj.isValid = (req, res, next) => {
    const {user} = User.authenticate()(req.user.username, req.body.currentPassword).then(user => {
        if(!user.username && user.error) {
            req.flash("error", "The password you entered does not match the current password stored in the database, please try again");
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            res.locals.user = user;
            next();     
        }   
    });
}
```

and thanks Mickael B for your help as well